# How to lazy process an xml documentwith hexpat?

Tags: xml, haskell

In my search for a haskell library that can process large (300-1000mb) xml files i came across [hexpat](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/hexpat). There is [an example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hexpat/) in the Haskell Wiki that claims to

```
-- Process document before handling error, so we get lazy processing.
```

For testing purposes i have redirected the output to `/dev/null` and throw a 300mb file at it. Memory consumption kept rising until i had to kill the process.

Now i removed the error handling from the `process` function:

```
process :: String -> IO ()
process filename = do
  inputText <- L.readFile filename
  let (xml, mErr) = parse defaultParseOptions inputText :: (UNode String,     Maybe XMLParseError)

  hFile <- openFile "/dev/null" WriteMode
  L.hPutStr hFile $ format xml
  hClose hFile

  return ()
```

As a result the function now uses constant memory. Why does the error handling result in massive memory consumption?

As far as i understand `xml` and `mErr` are two seperate unevaluated thunks after the call to `parse`. Does `format xml` evaluate `xml` and build the evaluation tree of 'mErr'? If yes is there a way to handle the error while using constant memory?

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hexpat/

Comment: Could someone with enough reputation add a `hexpat` tag to this question please?

Comment: Done—more than a year later.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak with authority on hexpat, but in general, error handling will force you to read the entire file into memory. If you want to only print out the result if there are no errors anywhere in the input, you need to read the entire input before producing output.

As I said, I don't really know hexpat, but with xml-conduit, you could do something like:

```
try $ runResourceT $ parseFile def inputFile $$ renderBytes def =$ sinkFile outputFile
```

It will use constant memory, and if there are any errors in processing, it will throw an exception (which the `try` will catch). The downside is that the output file may be corrupt. My guess is that your best bet is to output to a temporary file, and after the entire process is complete, move the temporary file to the output file. On any exception, just delete the temporary file.

Comment: hmm... i am actually confused by all those xml libraries in haskell. *HXT* seems to be the 'nicest' (ie most expressive and complete) api. But i had no sucess working with large files. *Hexpat* actually works fine as long as i don't touch the *err* value.